# Silenceing Excel 2013 Error "We couldn't free up space on the Clipboard. Another program might be using it right now"

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, clipboard

I understand that the above error appears when there is a program installed which is incompatible with excel. I don't want to "fix" the underlying issue which is causing the error to popup, because other than the popup itself I am not experiencing any workflow issues, and I need all my other software as-is. Excel copy/paste works fine, and drag and drop works fine, but I just keep getting this popup. Excel does exactly what I want it to do, but it thinks it has to tell me useless information about the clipboard while it's doing it.

I want to silence the popup. Is there a method to make excel just ignore the situation which causes this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Just for additional info... I've read the similarly titled question. It's asking a different thing. I don't need to fix the problem; I just want to make the error go away, and the recommendations for fixing the problem didn't work for me.

Comment: To understand what the error means: Excel has a build-in clipboard manager which syncs its content to the Windows clipboard when you copy, so that you can copy to other programs. When you get this error, the excel clipboard could not be synced with the windows clipboard, but the excel clipboard still works. I don't actually know how to disable the message though. Just wanted you to know what it actually means.

Comment: you could have a window-watching macro running and when the window about it appears, it would click the ok button.  It would still show up for a 1/2 second or so, but that's the best you can do.    Really though, you must close any open app that is set to auto-read the clipboard:  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-2016-error-we-couldnt-free-up-space-on-the/6a70ebde-f3be-47b0-8521-c3d3ebbf80bb  (read comments also)